# MSTest context and TLS version

Tags: c#, jenkins, mstest

We have a unit test that needs to connect to a TLS v1.1+ endpoint.

The test will fail if we don't force the TLS version to v1.1 or higher in the test context.

But out side of the text context, the code works fine even if we don't force it.

Our conclusion is that MSTest context reset TLS version to 1.0 or SSL3 even if the server can use TLS 1.1 or higher.

We are forcing the TLS version with the code below, but wonder why we are having this problem at all. The MSTest we use is deployed from Visual Studio Test Agent 2015 and Jenkins ran by Jenkins.

```
[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```

Comment: Can you please check if there is any difference in .net framework for both the actual and test project! Also to which framework version msbuild in Jenkins targeted

Comment: @MaheshB They are both .net 4.6.1. MS Build is v15. MS Test is v14.